# Why is my delegate not receiving this selector?

Tags: xcode

I've got an error that I don't understand.

I have a class to help out with print jobs:

```
//.h

@interface PrintDelegate : NSObject <UIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) FFDetailViewController* controller;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableData*    pdf;
@property (assign) int          pageCount;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray*          fields;
@property (weak, nonatomic)   UIPrintInteractionController* printController;

- (id) initWithPageCount:(int)pc forFields:(NSArray*)flds Controller:(FFDetailViewController*)ctlr;
- (int) printFromButton: (UIBarButtonItem*) btn;
- (void) makePDF;
- (void) shift:(PixelShiftDirection)dir pixelCount:(int)amt;
- (void) adjustFields;
- (void) onPrintComplete;

@end
```

When printing is complete I display an alert to ask if the user wants to adjust the printout (and print again).

```
//.m
- (void) onPrintComplete
{
    UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Printing Complete" message:@"Would you like to adjust the field positions?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Adjust", nil];

    [alert show];
}

- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString* clickedButton = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if ([clickedButton isEqualToString:@"Adjust"]) 
    {
        [self adjustFields];
    }
}
```

When I tap either button in the alert, I get an error similar to this:

```
-[__NSArrayM alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

The object receiving the bad selector is always something strange, (I've also seen **NSCFArrayM and __NSMallocBlock**). The selector is a method from the UIAlertViewDelegate Protocol. I don't understand why the selector is being sent to some incorrect object rather than my PrintDelegae object.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted looks ok to me (although the UIAlertView may ultimately leak).  From your description of the errors, it may be that you have some heap corruption, potentially caused by releasing a pointer to the same object more than once.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you are most likely not retaining `PrintDelegate` correctly. The longer version is you should examine the life cycle of `PrintDelegate` instance. It needs to live long enough for the handle the clickedButton callback. You could try setting a breakpoint in the `PrintDelegate`'s `-dealloc` method and see when and how it's getting called.

Answer (score 0):

`__NSArrayM` is a mutable array. Either you're passing the wrong object as the delegate, or it's being released, deallocated, reallocated, and reinitialized before the delegate method is called. Since you're also getting `NSCFArrayM`, another mutable array, and `__NSMallocBlock`, which I infer to be an allocated but not-yet-initialized block of memory, I'd suggest the second. Check your memory management between creating the alert view and dismissing it. You may want to try the XCode analysis and profiling tools, they're surprisingly good.